# Formatting xtable with different digit sizes

Tags: tables, xtable

I have a data.frame in R with three columns,

```
A=cbind(c(1,2),c(10^4,10^3),c(4535.45,324.252))
```

is there a way to generate a LaTeX table, using `xtable`, such that:

- The first appears like `1 $ 2 \\`
- The second appears like `$ 1 x10^4$ & $1x 10^3$` (only 1 significant figure is kept),
- The third keeps 3 significant figures: `$4.53 x 10^4$ & $3.24 x 10^3$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
<<results='asis',echo=F>>=
library(xtable)
A=cbind(c(1,2),c(10^4,10^3),c(4535.45,324.252))
print(xtable(A, display = c("g","g","g","g"), 
digits=c(1,1,1,-2)), math.style.exponents = T,
include.rownames=F,booktabs=T)
@
\end{document}
```